# NS-2 allinone 2.35 works find with Mac OS X Mavericks 10.9?

Tags: macos, ns2

I've been struggling to install NS-2 with allinone for a day.

But every time it throws errors related to X11, C and C++, WIN32 (I don't know why this happens), deprecated functions and so many things.

With my poor knowledge about programming languages, I've tried to modify the sources and it seems progress in some ways.

However, errors continuously occur. And I totally gave it up.

What's wrong with this ns-allinone?

I heard that there are big changes in Mac OS X between 10.8 and 10.9 and also in Xcode between v4 and v5. Is this might be problem?

Or, ns-allinone-2.35 does not completely support Mac OS X Mavericks?

Answer (score 0):

I made a patch to solve this problem. Just follow the tips in my github project and you will get no error. https://github.com/csujedihy/macos10.9_ns2.35_patch
Moreover, NS2.35 is completely supported by Marvericks. These erros are some mistakes in `confiugre` file and `Makefile` file. Also,some minor compatibility problems in `clang` compiler.